# How to hide navigation controller for UISearchController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

I currently running into a question for the new `UISearchController` in iOS 8.
I have a root navigation controller but I hide it since I have a customized top bar. However, when I push to the search controller, the nav bar always come back, and it also make my root screen's nav bar appear again.

I tried in the root screen's `viewWillAppear`, set `navigationBar` hidden, but that not working.

I searched so much is all about how to unhide the nav bar, anyone has same issue like me on how to hide it ? I don't wanna animation at all.

Answer (score 1):

The class [`UISearchController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/) have a property entitled [`hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchController/hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation) that determines whether the navigation bar is hidden during searching, you can set to `true` like in the following example:

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
```

I hope this help you.